# Открыть файл на чтение из jar

Tags: java, jar

Есть jar-ник, с ним в папке лежит некий text.txt. Jar-ник должен открыть этот файл и считать с него информацию. На методы вроде:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("text.txt");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

выдает NullPointerException, как быть?

Answer (score 2):

```
public void readFile(String filename) {
    File f=new File(filename);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInput = null;
    int bytesRead = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try {
        bufferedInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        while ((bytesRead = bufferedInput.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            sb.append(new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead, "windows-1251"));

        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found" + e);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Exception while reading the file " + ioe);
    }
    finally {
        try{
            if(bufferedInput != null)
                bufferedInput.close();
            }
        catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("Error while closing the stream : " + ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, при запуске проекта в NetBeanse все работает, когда пытаюсь запустить jar-ник: FileNotFounExeption

Comment: @AlexTeos Начнем с того, что в любой метод можно передать null. А дальше компилятор выбирает наиболее узкую версию метода из возможных. В данном случае FileNotFoundException это подкласс IOException, который, в свою очередь, подкласс Object. Поэтому компилятор выбирает именно данный метод. Отсюда следует, что в ваш метод никакой файл не передается, а передается null. ПУСТО!

Answer (score 1):

`getResourceAsStream()` ищет ресурс в `CLASSPATH`, очевидно ваш файл не в `CLASSPATH`, добавьте путь к файлу в манифест JAR'а поле `Class-Path`. Как [показано здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)